# Showing user count of records only when Insert completes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SIS package that runs daily. It has a script task to call a stored procedure (`LoadRecords`) which inserts millions of records into a table.

When the package is finished, I need to show only the latest records to the user. Anyone doing `select count(1) from RecordsTbl` should only be able to see latest count from when package finished. If they query in between load process they should see last loaded count records.

What change should I make to the stored procedure to achieve this?

Comment: SQL doesn't work like that. `select count(1) from RecordsTbl` will always count **ALL** of the records in `RecordsTbl`, no matter what you do. If you want the user to only count some of the records, you have to rely on them adding a `WHERE` clause to that query. Unless, that is, you're will to let the procedure completely `DELETE` the previous records first.

Comment: I want to prevent user from reading the table in between counts, for example if existing records in table are 1000 and package starts inserting another 100, then show final 1100 to user once completed or 1000 if insertion going on and not in between record count like 1010..1020 etc if user querying in between.Can I lock the table or do something similar?

Comment: put a batch identifier or batch date to your table and query that as max and get the count...

Comment: this is not too clear.. where is you stored proc? It can't be done with asking only a question.